# How to allow a Java based application to bind to low port

Tags: systemd, java

I need to run a certain application on a CentOS 7.5 based system. This application needs to bind to port 389 in order to expose a ldap service.
This application is run by SystemD but fails to start because the user I have to use for running the app is not allowed to bind to ports lower than 1024.
I already tried to `setcap 'cap_net_bind_service=+ep' /opt/jdk8/bin/java` but after this Java is not even able to start.

I've already seen solutions based on iptables forward, ssh tunnels etcetera. All of this "magic" is not allowed on the system I have to use. I guess the same applies to `setcap`.

Is there some setting I can use within SystemD ? I am sure it can somehow be done because I have to run `nginx` on port `80` with the same user and there it works.

As I don't have the sourcecode of the application I can not change the way it opens the port.

Comment: I normally just use `sudo` is that also not an option?

Comment: @Jesse_b: Can you please be more specific ? Is this a setting I could use within the SystemD service definition ? A normal `sudo /opt/jdk/bin/java -jar foo.jar` does not do the job

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413807/is-there-a-way-for-non-root-processes-to-bind-to-privileged-ports-on-linux. Shows *many* methods.

Answer (score 1):

If you could give java (or anything that uses dynamic libraries) elevated capabilities, then an attacker could switch the libraries, to gain capabilities.

## A solution

Write a minimal C program (statically linked), have it open the port, and attach it to file descriptor 3. And then exec the java program. The java program will have to do an fdopen, to make it look like a file from java's point of view (`open "/dev/fd/3"`) This wrapper would need the capabilities.

Comment: I guess this is what nginx does. I would be able to code in C or golang, but I would prefer an approach which only involves SystemD _native_ settings. Unfortunately I can not change the code of the application.

Answer (score 1):

There are many solutions that you can enlist here, since you're using systemd this would seem to be the way to go, using `ListenStream`:

```
$ cat /etc/systemd/system/gitea.socket
[Unit]
Description=Gitea socket

[Socket]
ListenStream=80
NoDelay=true
```

And then once you've defined your `.socket` file define your unit file like so using it:

```
[Unit]
Description=Gitea (Git with a cup of tea)
Requires=gitea.socket
After=syslog.target
After=network.target
After=postgresql.service

[Service]
RestartSec=2s
Type=simple
User=git
Group=git
WorkingDirectory=/home/git/go/src/code.gitea.io/gitea
ExecStart=/home/git/go/src/code.gitea.io/gitea/gitea web
Restart=always
Environment=USER=git HOME=/home/git
NonBlocking=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

#### References

- [Is there a way for non-root processes to bind to “privileged” ports on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413807/is-there-a-way-for-non-root-processes-to-bind-to-privileged-ports-on-linux)
- [[Howto] Run programs as non-root user on privileged ports via Systemd](https://liquidat.wordpress.com/2018/01/04/howto-run-programs-as-non-root-user-on-privileged-ports-via-systemd/)

Comment: I did this (added the `myapp.socket`, changed to `ListenStream=389`, added `Requires` and `After`) and `systemctl daemon-reload`ed. But when I `systemctl start myapp` I still get a `Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied` error.